# How to get selected item in listview by clicking button

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a listview with textView and a button in each line, i'm trying to get the text by clicking on the button not by clicking the whole line but the adapterView method:(AdapterView arg0, View v,int position, long arg3) is not working for buttons click.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Set the view for each item in the list view
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.employeeitem, null);
        }
        //Get the Textviews from the row view and set the appropriate values for them
        TextView labelName=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.labelName);
        TextView labelAddress=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.labelAddress);
        TextView labelImmat=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.labelImmat);
        labelName.setText(array[position].marque);
        labelAddress.setText(array[position].categorie);
       labelImmat.setText(array[position].Prix_Achats);
        return v;
    }
```

This is how I select item by clicking the line of the listview but, I want to select item by clickin on the button not the whole line:

```
listEmployeeDetails.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long arg3)
     {

             TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.labelName);
             String name=tv.getText().toString();


             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact Selected "+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
    });
```

Comment: post your adapter getView code.

Answer (score 2):

set an onClickListener to your button:

```
Button button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
       // button was clicked
    }

});
```

Comment: That's not my problem , my problem is how to get the text in listview line by clicking the button

Answer (score 1):

You can set a tag to the button to access it from `getView()` method. In the tag you can store the text of the item when you are declaring it programatically or via xml.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Set the view for each item in the list view
    View v = convertView;
    //Do your view stuff here
    Button btn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str = (String)v.getTag();
            //Do whatever you want with your str here
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

get text from textview by clicking on a button

```
    btn.setTag(textView.getText().toString());
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String s =(String)v.getTag();


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar using a cursor adapter.

Inside your adapter define the onClickListener. Before that you will have to use `getTag` and `setTag` functions to send and retreive the information you want to recover inside the function.

```
myButton.setTag("Value I want to store");

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String value = (String) v.getTag();
            //Whatever you want to do
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

`parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()`

This method returns the current selected item at that position

Answer (score -1):

It took me three days to solve this problem but the solution was quite obvious. My list is inflated from `SQL` server using `JSONArray` and what I had to do in the `getView()` method was simply to pass the `TextView` into the button's `setTag()` after I have inflated it with jsonOjbect. Then in the button's `onClick()` method I had to get the tag. Take a look at the code, hope I help.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ListCell cell;//ListCell is my widgets class holder

    //set up the convertView

    if(convertView==null){

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_custom_layout, null);
        cell=new ListCell();
        cell.Diet=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dietEat); //Diet is the custom list layout textview
        cell.eatButton=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eatButtton); //eatButton is the button to be clicked
        cell.eatButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }else{
        cell=(ListCell)convertView.getTag();

    }

    //Change data of each cell
    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject=this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);
        cell.Diet.setText(jsonObject.getString("food_name"));
        cell.eatButton.setTag(cell.Diet.getText()); //Tag for button's onclick Listener

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return convertView;
}

                @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

String fud=(String) v.getTag(); //Getting the tag and parsing it to string

}
```